# Google Sheets Count Cells Starting with "?"

Tags: google-sheets

I am making a research template, and I have come across a problem while trying to code. I have cells which have "?", stating that they are "to be researched". But, some of them have more than one question mark, and I would like to be able to know if the cell starts with "?". How do I figure out how many cells start with a question mark in a range? Anything will help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=countif(range,"~?*")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also get the list of strings starting with `?`:

`=QUERY({A:A},"select * where Col1 like '?%'")`

or

`=FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(A:A,"^\?"))`